# How can I return all the subdocuments for an array of objects in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to search through the document TreatmentPlan for the subdocument in treatments that matches the clientId provided:

This is the TreatmentPlan model:

```
const treatmentPlanSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id: String,
    clientId: String,
    startDate: Date,
    clientGoals: String,
    objectivesOfTreatmentPlan: String,
    conclusionOfTreatmentPlan: String,
    endDate: Date,
    treatments: [treatmentSchema]
})
```

This is the treatments subdocument:

```
const treatmentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id: String,
    clientId: String,
    date: String,
    time: String,
    price: String
})
```

And this is the call I'm trying to make in Node:

```
export const getTreatmentsByClientId = async (req, res) => {
    const { clientId: id } = req.params
    try {
        const result = await TreatmentPlan.find({clientId: id})
        const treatments = result.treatments.find(({clientId})=>clientId === id)
        console.log(treatments)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
}
```

When I run this, the error I get is "cannot read property 'find' of undefined."

I ran a similar function on a different array and it worked, but it doesn't seem to work for this array. Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `find` query:

```
db.collection.find({
  "clientId": 1,
  "treatments.clientId": 1
},
{
  "_id": 0,
  "treatments.$": 1
})
```

Where in the projection you are telling mongo "give me the `treatments` where the condition given (i.e. `treatments.clientId: 1`) is true".

But be careful, this only returns the first match. Check [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NuFMO1dT_4Q) where there are two `clientId` but only one is returned.

If there are more objects you can use `$filter` in an aggregate query like this:

- First `$match` by "parent" clientId and then filter the `treatments` array to get only objects where `clientId` is the desired one.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "clientId": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "treatments": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$treatments",
          "cond": {"$eq": ["$$this.clientId",1]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rW2hgPUZQ7s)